# smoothest way to change jquery.animate mid-animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

I am animating an element on the screen using jQuery.animate in response to the window scroll event like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  $("#myElement").stop().animate({top: -0.5 * $(window).scrollTop()});
});
```

Since the scroll event fires over and over when you're scrolling a window, I have to call the .stop() function on my element in order to immediately start my next animation.

This seems to work okay, but can be a bit slow when there's a lot of content being animated. Is there a better way to update the target values of an animation mid-animation? What can I do to improve the performance of this code?

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever thought of just doing a more specific `.css` change?

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  $("#myElement").css({top: -0.02 * $(window).scrollTop()});
});
```

I just put in an arbitrary number, but it might be worth trying and playing with.  It should be smoother if you figure out the right modifiers.

Also: It'd be nice if you accepted a few more answers. You have only accepted 31% of the questions you've asked. Just a thought.

Comment: I actually am using .animate so that I can have easing. If I do .css, then there's no transition.

Comment: You mean so it slides smoothly?  You can do that with css.  I do it on my website.